# How to operate on dates?

Tags: linux

I have tried the following command to display the current time:

```
date +%T
```

Output:

```
15:03:29
```

What Linux command should I use to get the following output?

```
15:03:29
15:04:39
15:05:49
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do (the "bigger problem", not the sub-task you've narrowed it down to)? Right now, it seems like you just want to repeat a command three times in a row and wait 70 seconds between each repetition…

Comment: Not three times it should repeat n times  either 60 seconds or 70 seconds interval

Comment: Should it repeat until you manually terminate it, or do you want it to stop automatically under a certain condition?

Comment: it should automatically terminate after nth field completed.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want. How to get `15:03:29`? - `echo '15:03:29'`. But I suppose, that's not what you meant. So please clarify. N.B. The tag `linux` is for questions specifically related to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

To display the time 3 times with 70 seconds interval

```
for i in {0..2}
do
    date +%T -d "$((70*$i)) seconds"
done
```

Comment: Cant we use direct linux command to view it.

Comment: If the command is `date3`, you can put the code in `/usr/bin/date3` and use `date3` directly in your terminal.

Comment: What does meant by date3

Comment: It is an example of name for your new command. Replace date3 by anything you want. It is also possible to create a bash function.